# g++ not able to find include directories despite absolute addresses being passed in

Tags: ubuntu, include, g++, cygwin

I'm working on some C++ code that includes the use of tinyXML for some small XML parsing. Since I know Python but not make, I'm using scons and getting the following scons output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o Release-cygwin/SDLWin.o -c -ISDLWin -I/cygdrive/d/Jason/Projects/Libraries/tinyxml/2.6.2/
 -I/cygdrive/d/Jason/Projects/Libraries/boost-1.47.0/boost_1_47_0/
 -I/cygdrive/d/Jason/Projects/Libraries/sdl/1.2.14/include SDLWin/SDLWin.cpp
SDLWin/SDLWin.cpp:36:21: fatal error: tinyxml.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [Release-cygwin/SDLWin.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I've checked the paths, and they are OK. This project builds fine using VS2010 using the same include paths (tho they aren't prefaced with /cygdrive!)

The LOC in question is simply

```
#include "tinyxml.h"
```

I tried with using the DOS-like path specifications instead of cygwin, but that produced wierd include paths instead. All the commentary I've seen on this error suggests that the paths are screwed up or not set or something, but I'm using absolute paths to the same include file that VS is including, so not sure what's going on.

TIA,
-J

Edit: I've now got an Ubuntu 11 (64-bit) vm and attempting to build the code using scons on that results in the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [man page](http://www.scons.org/doc/0.96.1/HTML/scons-man.html), `scons` on Win32 prefers to use the MinGW tool chain.  It might not even know how to find the Cygwin `g++` command.  (Have you installed MinGW?)

If I recall correctly, MinGW uses MSYS, which has some similarities to Cygwin but is (deliberately) much less capable.  In particular, I think MSYS refers to the `D:\` Windows drive as `/D`, not `/cygdrive/D`.

Either adjust your SConscript files (and source code, if necessary) to be compatible with MinGW, or figure out how to make `scons` invoke the Cygwin gcc toolchain.

Comment: Scons only prefers MinGW over Cygwin in win32 builds when using the *Windows-native* python interpreter. I'm running this directly from the cygwin prompt, so that's not an issue. The fact that gcc/g++ is executing and producing output means that it is definitely being found; a "which g++" yields "/usr/bin/g++" which is what would be called given scons is not specifying a path to the tool. BTW, no I don't have mingw installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out none of cygwin, python, ubuntu or gcc. I call scons from the top-level directory, but it traverses down a directory level to the code and the SConscript file... which meant the paths weren't correct when passed down. The actual -I paths are the same, but adding an additional "../" on the front of the environment variables that I use to set the paths to boost, etc., meant that it worked.

Comment: you should add this as a comment to an answer or a comment on your question rather than an answer in its own right.